# LDAP для PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, ldap

Требуется выгружать информацию о пользователях из Active Directory средствами PostgreSQL.

Я в интернете нашел несколько дополнений, которые предоставляют такую возможность: multicorn и ldap_fdw.

Проблема в том, что я не могу сообразить как отфильтровать результат, который я получаю через эти дополнения.

К примеру multicorn позволяет задать каталог, где производить поиск (path) и объект поиска (objectClass). Но этого не достаточно. К примеру необходимо отфильтровать результат. Ограничить людей, состоящих в определенной группе.

Как это сделать?